# Angular TypeScript How to see specific value of dynamically generated children in parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component named 'Quiz'. In this component, I generate several instances of child components depending on an index value that comes from a service (that I subscribe to in the initializer).

This is the HTML code of the parent (Quiz)

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="accordion" *ngFor="let item of quizFlowitemsArray; let key=index">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">{{ item.name }}</button></h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <app-question (questionFormValid)="childEventHandler($event)"></app-question> // child component
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="margin-20"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block pull-right" style="font-weight: bold" [disabled]="!isQuestionFormValid">Add</button></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

In the child component named 'Question', there is a formgroup. This form is dynamic - which in my case means you can add a question to this form or remove one. This results in an array of questions.

This is the TS code of the Child (Question) component where the question gets added

```
  addQuestion() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.addQuestionsForm.controls['questions'];
    control.push(this.initQuestions());
    console.log(control);
  }

  initQuestions(){
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      qtype: ['', [Validators.required]],
      value: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

I now need to access this array (named control) of questions from the parent component per instance of the child component, as each of the children generated can have questionlists that vary in size and content. Ultimately I would like to append this array to a two dimensional array so that the index represents the child component 'id'.
How should I best approach this?

I can provide more code or a plnkr if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options in my opinion:

1. Using Input/Output properties and have your child component Emit an event to which you react in the parent component, [here's some documentation on that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM)
2. Implement REDUX in your application if you feel like it'll grow to a point where using input/output properties will become too hard to maintain and keep track off, [here's some good documentation on that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P5DTlg9oLc)

I personally prefer using REDUX for most applications although I can see it not being worth the hassle for a small project.

Comment: I've actually watched that video and have found it very useful (as you can see I have already implemented one event emitter for another value). 
Though my question is actually more aimed at how I grab the identity of the child containing that value, if that makes sense. How do I know which one of the child instances is communicating which value to me?

I do find the REDUX approach very interesting and might look to implement this instead (eventually). However, I will most likely keeps things simple for the first version since I've already gone down the event emitter route. Thank you!

Comment: I've started a chat as it's a bit more lengthy, I see you declare the index already as KEY when you use *ngFor. Now what I would do in the child component is create an index INPUT property @input() index; and then when you itterate the child component you use [index]="key", does that make sense?